# Photos with a name ending in _n.jpg

Tags: macos, iphone, high-sierra, photos

I have an iMac running High Seirra. I have quite a few photos on my mac that have names consisting of something like this: 11008553_991594160872293_5946103255845449374 and ending in _n.jpg. These look like normal jpegs but i don't understand the naming. What are these files?  They originally came from my iPhone.

Comment: open one and then use Get info

Comment: I've done that but I see nothing revealing. It says its a jpeg image.

Comment: what kind of photos are those, like screen shot iPhone camera, did you take them

Comment: The ones i've checked were photos taken with a phone camera and then either texted to me or maybe downloaded from a facebook account. There are also photos with the same long names but only  ,JPG extension. Those were taken by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My research shows that images downloaded from Facebook always ends with “_n.jpg” !

So you must have downloaded them from Facebook to your phone.

iCloud then synced them with your Mac, unless you transferred them your self.

Comment: All the photos are just snapshots of family and friends. Some are definitely facebook dowloads but I seem to recall some being texted to me. I couldn't swear to it though. And maybe the person who texted me downloaded from facebook initially. I don't know.  But thanks for the facebook info.

Comment: do not swear now :)

Comment: lol!!  i won't..  unless my teams are losing!

Comment: I was looking for raw images before they were converted to jpegs.